# Custom Gallery is deprecated in android?

Tags: android, gallery, onkeydown

The type Gallery is deprecated. 
The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) from the type Gallery is deprecated.
**Sample Code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class mygallery extends Gallery {
    public mygallery(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(ctx, attrSet);
    }

    private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){ 
           return e2.getX() > e1.getX(); 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
      int kEvent;
      if(e2.getX() > e1.getX()){
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
      }
      else{
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
      }
      onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
      return true;  
    }
}
```

How to solve this deprecated

Comment: deprecate means that the Android team will not more mantain the Gallary. What do you wanna solve?

Comment: what is the alternate solution.

Comment: Horizontal scroll view or list view Horizontal

Comment: The Android team suggests to implent the same beahaviour with a ViewPager

Comment: Don't pass null to onKeyDown!

Answer (score 0):

Use default gallery in xml file and create its ImageAdapter with your custom view.It will be done in getView() of that Adapter.